# Lambda and API Gateway on the same VPC resulting in User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I'm trying to learn about resource policies and permissions in general in AWS.
The idea that started as something easy, an API Gateway denying access to everything but other resources in the same VPC ended as a nightmare.

What I want: My API allowing traffic/calls only to resources on the same VPC.

So I created 2 subnets and an open Security Group (all traffic inbound and outbound just for testing purposes)

I created an API Gateway with integrating to a Lambda function and another lambda function and deploy them to that VPC.

The API Gateway has one resource /hi and allows just GET.
When you hit that path it proxies to Lambda which returns a simple message: Hi.

The other lambda (which is on the same VPC) makes a call to the API and returns an error or the response.

Until now, everything works well. The lambda function hits API Gateway which poxies to lambda and return Hi.

But, as I said, I want to play with permissions. So I decided to lock down the calls to API Gateway to the VPC where both reside.

So I added this resource policy to API Gateway:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:account-id:api-id/*/*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:sourceVpc": "vpc-id"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:account-id:api-id/*/*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I went to the lambda (not the one that is part of the service, if not the one that invokes API Gateway) and add the Managed Policy

- AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
- Also an inline policy allowing execute-api:Invoke on the resource arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:account-id:api-id/*/*/*

When I run again the lambda function (which was working previously with both, my API Gateway and dummy apis like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) I receive the following error:

```
INFO    json {
  Message: 'User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:account-id:api-id/dev/GET/hi with an explicit deny'
}
```

If I removed the resource policy in API Gateway, it works again... As soon as I add it, it retrieves the same error.

Does anyone know why this happens?
I'm turning crazy. I will appreciate help.

---

Edition: Trying an IAM role and resource policy

I also tried to use a role.
For this, in the API I set the following resource policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/my-role-for-API-Gateway"
            },
            "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:account-id:api-id/*/*/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, I attached that role to my lambda function (the one that should be able to invoke the API).
Important: That lambda is not part of the service. It is a separate Lambda that should be able to call API Gateway which will proxy the request to the lambda that it is part of the service.

I attached the following policies to that role.

- AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole (because I also tried within the same VPC)
- AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess (open permission just to be sure I was not missing anything)
- Inline policy allowing the invocation of the API by resource ARN: arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:account-id:api-id/*/*/*

I even tried giving AdministratorAccess to that role just to exhaust possibilities.

I test through API Gateway console, and I receive the proper console.
When I test through Lambda console, I receive the following error:

```
INFO    json {
  Message: 'User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: execute-api:Invoke on resource: arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:account-id:api-id/dev/GET/hi'
}
```

So the question for this block would be: how a lambda could invoke an API Gateway which is restricting access to a specific role which the lambda has?

Comment: Can you clarity? You are using private API? How exactly is your second lambda invoking the api from VPC? Going through NAT gateway?

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Marcin
I'm not using a private API, just a regional one.
The lambda is just fetching the dns endpoint provided by API gateway,
I will appreciate any advice. I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the issue is that `aws:SourceVpc` condition can be only used for **private API**. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-aws-condition-keys.html):

> aws:SourceVpc - This key can be used **only for private APIs**.

Since you are using **regional** API, your `StringNotEquals` will not work, and you are getting **explicit deny**.

If you want to use `aws:SourceVpc`, you have to modify your api to be private API. But if its only learning experience for resource-based policies, the simplest way to learn them would be with **bucket policies**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that tip. I totally missed it.
What would you recommend me for a non-private API?
I want to lock down the access to that API just from another API Gateway or Lambda but maybe having some resources publicly available. Let's say that /public could be accessed by everyone but not /hi.
I tried also to set a role as principal and add that role to Lambda, but that didn't work either. Again, thanks a lot

Comment: @Peter API gateway policies are tricky. You would have to provide more details why using IAM role for lambda also did not work. You can add the relevant details, error messages, lambda code in a new question if you want. This way others could also see it and help.

Comment: Yes. I'm turning crazy, lol. I know that I'm a newbie but somehow my logic makes sense in my mind but not in the resources. Restrict use to an API Gateway to a specific role. Add that role to a lambda function with some permissions.  I added a block in my question: Trying an IAM role and resource policy
Thanks a lot

Comment: @Peter But how do you call the API from lambda? You can't just normally call it using `requests` in python or similar way in other languages? I think you really should make new question with your lambda function code. Its difficult to speculate on your comments only.

Comment: I was trying to fetch and using the native node module https which is similar to requests. I thought I was able to do it from lambda console. Sorry to keep bothering you, but do you know some resources to understand how to interact with API gateway with that lambda without having to proxy the requests to that Lambda? Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Thanks! Yeap! I thought I did it. Would you mentor people who are learning was or something similar? I'm learning and I don't have a lot of economic resources but I would love to retribute :)